# Book/chapter/article recommendation for beginners level confirmatory factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis, references, teaching, confirmatory-factor

I am looking for a text that will help me provide explanations suited to undergraduate level. I've found that Andy Field's "Discovering Statistics Using..." series allowed me to pitch things at the right level for Exploratory Factor Analysis but it has no chapter on CFA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007HHCMK0) by J. Scott Long should suit your purposes.

EDIT: The book is *Confirmatory Factor Analysis* published by Sage as part of their "Quantitative applications in the social sciences" series.

Comment: Could you update the post to include a full title of the book? The link has gone dead...